# Unable to store the list item value using session storage in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, session-storage

I click on a link then it's updating the count column value in the list. But after reloading the site, the count column value becomes 0 in the list. I am updating the count value using **count** variable and included that variable in rest api data to increment the count to that list item. So, I have tried my best including session storage property in the code but it again becomes 0 after reloading the site. Please help and correct me if I have done any mistake in the code.

```
var count = 0;

function updateItems() {

count = count + 1;

var resturl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('demo')/getItemById(1)";
var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName('demo');

    $.ajax({
           url: resturl,
           type: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify({'__metadata': { 'type': itemType }, 'Count': count }),
           headers: {
           "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
           "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
           "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
           "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
           "IF-MATCH":"*"
            },
            
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onError
    });

   function onSuccess(data) {
   alert('List Item Updated');
   }

   function onError(error) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(error));
   }

   function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
   return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
   }
}


function storeCount(count) {

if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
if (sessionStorage.count) {

sessionStorage.count = Number(sessionStorage.count)+1;

} else {

sessionStorage.count = 1;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the code as this, use sessionStorage.setItem to save count into sessionStorage:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function updateItems() {

            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined")
            {
                if (sessionStorage.count) {

                    sessionStorage.setItem('count',Number(sessionStorage.count) + 1);

                } else {

                    sessionStorage.setItem('count',1);

                }
            }

            var resturl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('demo')/getItemById(1)";
            var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName('demo');

            $.ajax({
                url: resturl,
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': itemType }, 'Count': sessionStorage.count }),
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                    "IF-MATCH": "*"
                },

                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });

            function onSuccess(data) {
                alert('List Item Updated');
            }

            function onError(error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

            function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
                return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
            }
        }
       
    </script>
    <input type="button" onclick="updateItems()" value="Test"/>
```